# PhoneGap Social Sharing Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, socialshare

I am using social plugin in PhoneGap from below url:

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

I have done all setting given in above link.

My problem is that, when I am including "phonegap.js", it is working fine in Android.
But when I am including "cordova.js" and comment "phonegap.js" then it stops to work.

Can you please let me know why this is happening?

Actually, I am using login with facebook and "cordova.js" file is required to import in script. But when I am importing it, social sharing plugin stops to work. And I know, there is no need to add both files in script.

So, can anyone let me know what can be effective solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are the PhoneGap versions the same for both phonegap.js and cordova.js? Check the headers of both files.